ADC REF on STM32F103
I am building a project with STM32F103, where I need to measure couple of external voltages (From sensors, that produces analog voltage output) using ADC. I have printed 10 pcbs and it seems like the output of the 3.3V LDO is not exactly same on all boards. So I thought, it would be great if we can refer to the actual VDD to put that value in ADC calculation. As the ADC resolution is 12 BIT on the MCU, and if I measure a voltage of say 3.1V on the VDD, then I would know that the ADC reading of 4095 means 3.1V and calculate the ADC readings on the pins accordingly.
Now I am little confused with this MCU's internal Vref, where it says the value of the internal reference is about 1.2V.
My Question is what is this 1.2V? How should I take this in account while calculating ADC related stuffs?
I've seen people using this formula to measure VDD
VDD = 1.20 * 4096.0 / ADC_VAL
Using this formula.. VDD can never go beyond 1.2V. Is not it?
So my question is instead of just hard coding (3.3/4096) * ADC_VAL, if I can make it little better by knowing the actual VDDA on the chip, so that I can do it like (VDDA / 4096) * ADC_VAL

Internal reference voltage (VREFINT) on STM32F103 is "known" voltage which you can connect on ADC internal input. ADC reference is always VDDA (for example 3.3V). If you measure VREFINT (for example 1.1V) with 3.3V VDDA, then 1.1/3.3 * 4096=1365 will be result of ADC conversion. And you can calculate VDDA back by 4096/1365 * 1.1V=3.3V. If VDDA is known and well regulated voltage, then you don't need VREFINT. But if your VDDA is not well controlled, for example temparature variations change VDDA from 3.2V to 3.4V, you can use internal reference voltage to get precise value of VDDA voltage or any other ADC input.
Things are little bit complicated by fact that VREFINT voltage varies from chip to chip (single piece of STM32F103 have VREFINT=1.21V and another piece for example 1.17V). Manufacturer measure precise voltage value during chip fabrication and saves calibration constant to flash memory and you should read it (in runtime) to know what is individual VREFINT voltage.

The formula is correct. If you are measuring internal 1.2V with your e.g. 3.0V supply as reference, you get 1638 as the count.
Just solve the formula for VDD and it will work.
With 1.2*4096/1638 you get your 3.0V VDDA supply voltage back.
So you can measure VDDA, and then use VDDA in the calculations to find out what the measured sensor outputs really are.
